# Reusing a token obtained from DeviceCodeCredential

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I am using the following code to obtain a token for azure blob service:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential, DeviceCodeCredential, ClientSecretCredential

credential = DeviceCodeCredential(authority="login.microsoftonline.com", tenant_id="***", client_id="***")

blobber = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://***.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)

blobs = blobber.list_containers()
for b in blobs:
    print(b)
```

It works perfectly.

However, during a certain timeframe, a user may need to invoke the blob service more than once. The key point is that the process may close and reopen several times.

Making the user go through the interactive token acquisition process each time the process restarts would be very annoying. I would like to persist the token and reuse it in later flows until it expires (assume persistence is secure).

What type of credential should I use? ClientSecretCredential doesn't work. Alternatively, perhaps there is a token cache mechanism I am not aware of.

EDIT:

I reposted a [variation of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204464/reusing-a-token-obtained-from-interactivebrowsercredential). It also has a working answer. 
Thank you Jim Xu.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with the python libraries. But device code flow should give your app a refresh token that it should be able to use to get new access tokens without interaction.

Comment: Oh.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.devicecodecredential "This credential doesn't cache tokens--each get_token(*scopes, **kwargs) call begins a new authentication flow." This is quite a massive deficiency here :/

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76275253/11015298). It is written in the context of InteractiveBrowserCredential but should hold for other constructors too.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, the `DeviceCodeCredential` doesn't cache tokens--each `get_token(*scopes, **kwargs)` call begins a new authentication flow.
[image]

According to your need, you can use `ClientSecretCredential`. Regarding how to implement it, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role(such as Storage Blob Data Owner Storage Blob Data Contributor and Storage Blob Data Reader) to it to do Azure AD auth and access Azure blob storage. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli)

I use Azure CLI

```
#create a sevice pricipal and assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role at storage account level
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \ 
--scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>" --sdk-auth

# just assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role at storage account level
az role assignment create --assignee <sp_name> --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor role"
--scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
```

2. Code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
token_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
       sp_tenant_id,
       sp_application_id,
       sp_application_secret
   )

# Instantiate a BlobServiceClient using a token credential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=self.oauth_url, credential=token_credential)
blobs = blob_service_client.list_containers()
for b in blobs:
    print(b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jim, but my use case is a bit different. I _want_ the device flow, and want to later reuse its token, even after process restart.  The idea is to not bug the user too much. I am looking to provide an experience similar to the azure CLI ("az login") but through the programmatic interface.

Comment: @Vitaliy According to the situation, I think you need to implement device code flow by yourself. Regarding how to implement it, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-overview

Comment: I reposted a [variation of this question][1], which you answered. Thank you!