# Reusing a token obtained from InteractiveBrowserCredential

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I am running this code to obtain a Bearer token from the InteractiveBrowserCreedentail and log in to azure blob storage:

```
cred = InteractiveBrowserCredential(authority="login.microsoftonline.com", tenant_id="**", client_id="**")
token = cred.get_token()

print(token)

blobber = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://**.blob.core.windows.net", credential=cred)

blobs = blobber.list_containers()
for b in blobs:
    print(b)
```

This works well.

I am trying to reuse the token in another call, this time a direct rest interaction:

```
import requests

auth_header = ("Authorization", "Bearer " + "***")
version = ("x-ms-version", "2017-11-09")
response = requests.get("https://***.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list", headers=dict([auth_header, version]))
```

I get a 403 response saying:

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory), this should be working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please try to use the code ```token =cred.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation")``` to get access token

Comment: It works!
Can you elaborate _why_ does it work? Also - please post as Answer and I will accept.

Comment: I have posted my answer. Could you please accept it? It can help more people who have similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  my research, when you request AD access token and call Azure blob storage, the scope must contain `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` or `https://storage.azure.com/.default`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#get-an-oauth-token-from-azure-ad). In other words, the request url should be like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenat id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<>
&scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
&...
```

But when I run the `cred.get_token()`, the request url just be like below. The scope does not contain `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` or `https://storage.azure.com/.default`. So you cannot call Azure Blob rest api with the token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenat id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<>
&scope=offline_access openid profile&state=204238ac-4fcd-44f2-9eed-528ab4d9c37
&...
```

Meanwhile, I do test, if we run the code `blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://blobstorage0516.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=cred)`, the request url is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenat id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<>
&scope=https://storage.azure.com/.default offline_access openid profile&state=204238ac-4fcd-44f2-9eed-528ab4d9c37
&...
```

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution:

```
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential

class InteractiveAuthentication():

    def __init__(self):
        self.tenant_id: str = ""
        self.authority: str = ""
        self.client_id: str = ""
        self.resource_id: str = ""
        self.scope: str = f"{self.resource_id}/.default"
        self.token: str = ""

    def get_access_token(self):
        credential = DeviceCodeCredential(
            exclude_interactive_browser_credential=True,
            disable_automatic_authentication=True,
            tenant_id=self.tenant_id,
            authority=self.authority,
            client_id=self.client_id
        )
        self.token = credential._request_token(self.scope)
        return self.token['access_token']
```

Answer (score 0):

For general authentication caching and re-use, [this ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/23721) is particularly useful. I used that to build the below code which will ask for interactive authentication only if the cache file is missing or no longer valid.

```
# Test ability to use cached creds to avoid authenticating on every run

# ==============================================================================================================================================================
# Imports
# ==============================================================================================================================================================

import os

from azure.identity import (
    AuthenticationRecord,
    InteractiveBrowserCredential,
    TokenCachePersistenceOptions,
)
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

# ==============================================================================================================================================================
# Constants
# ==============================================================================================================================================================

CLIENT_ID = "redacted"

TENANT_ID = "redacted"

USERNAME = "redacted"

SCOPES = [
    "User.Read",
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared",
    "Mail.Send",
    "Mail.Send.Shared",
]

CACHE_FILE = "cred_cache.json"

# ==============================================================================================================================================================
# Functions
# ==============================================================================================================================================================


def main():
    # Actual credential caching is handled by Azure, but our app must supply the authentication record which identifies the tentant_id, username, etc.
    deserialized_record = None

    if os.path.exists(CACHE_FILE):
        with open(CACHE_FILE, "rt") as infile:
            cred_json = infile.read()
            deserialized_record = AuthenticationRecord.deserialize(cred_json)
        print("Read in from cache")

    print("Creating credential")
    credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential(
        cache_persistence_options=TokenCachePersistenceOptions(),
        authentication_record=deserialized_record,
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
    )
    print("Authenticating credential")
    record = credential.authenticate(scopes=SCOPES)

    print("Saving to file")
    cred_json = record.serialize()
    with open(CACHE_FILE, "wt") as outfile:
        outfile.write(cred_json)

    # Testing with an MSGraph query
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential, scopes=SCOPES)
    response = client.get("/me")
    print(f"{response = }")


# ==============================================================================================================================================================
# Main
# ==============================================================================================================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```